# Effect sizes for GLMs

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, effect-size, lsmeans, cohens-d

I'm just checking that I understand things correctly. If one wants Cohen's *d*-style effect sizes, and you have estimates from a GLM -- say a logit model -- there is no such thing--right? Because there is no error variance to reference.

Nonetheless, I came to the startling and upsetting realization that it's easy for users of the **emmeans** package to *think* they are computing Cohen's *d* in such situations, just by following examples in the documentation. For example:

```r
require(emmeans)
## Loading required package: emmeans

neuralgia.glm = glm(formula = Pain ~ Treatment * Sex + Age, 
                    family = binomial(), data = neuralgia)

EMM = emmeans(neuralgia.glm, ~ Treatment|Sex)

eff_size(EMM, sigma = sigma(neuralgia.glm), edf = df.residual(neuralgia.glm))
## Sex = F:
##  contrast effect.size   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  A - B          0.963 1.71 Inf     -2.38     4.306
##  A - P         -2.951 1.38 Inf     -5.66    -0.238
##  B - P         -3.915 1.57 Inf     -7.00    -0.829
## 
## Sex = M:
##  contrast effect.size   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  A - B          0.430 1.14 Inf     -1.80     2.663
##  A - P         -3.705 1.59 Inf     -6.83    -0.584
##  B - P         -4.135 1.69 Inf     -7.44    -0.829
## 
## sigma used for effect sizes: 0.9578 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This "works" because `sigma()` and `df.residual()` do return answers, albeit inappropriate ones. `sigma(neuralgia.glm)` returns the square root of the residual deviance divided by its d.f. -- and that is a measure of model fit, not anything like an appropriate reference for the effects in question.

Since I'm the **emmeans** developer, I think I can do something to keep users from doing this; it's just a shock that I have unwittingly enabled the production of meaningless results. And it sickens me to imagine how many times this has already been done.

And in fact I am kind of anti-effect-size in general. I provide the `eff_size()` function mostly because I figured out a way to incorporate the uncertainty in both the numerator of a ratio, and I figured that if people would look at those intervals (which they don't, but if they did...) they'd realize that in most cases, they'd be amazed how huge a range of Cohen's *d* values they have, and thus be persuaded (correctly, in my view) to decline to report them.

Please note that I am not asking for what are appropriate effect size measures for a GLM. I am sure there are some, but that's of little interest to me, and I do see in the answer to [another posting on a similar subject](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555242/effect-size-interpretation-for-glm-logit)
a suggestion that one use the odds ratios as effect-size measures. That can certainly be done:

```r
confint(contrast(EMM, "pairwise", type = "response"))
## Sex = F:
##  contrast odds.ratio     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  A / B        2.5154 4.1026 Inf  0.055020   115.002
##  A / P        0.0592 0.0782 Inf  0.002680     1.308
##  B / P        0.0235 0.0351 Inf  0.000711     0.779
## 
## Sex = M:
##  contrast odds.ratio     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  A / B        1.5089 1.6461 Inf  0.117026    19.456
##  A / P        0.0288 0.0434 Inf  0.000839     0.987
##  B / P        0.0191 0.0306 Inf  0.000443     0.819
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95 
## Conf-level adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
## Intervals are back-transformed from the log odds ratio scale
```

To understand how useful these results are, take a look at those confidence intervals!

Comment: Is your question just, 'is there such a thing as a Cohen's d type effect size for logistic regression'?  That's the only "?" I see.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am asking